# Data Tables - columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

are there any way to add new column to the table with JQuery plugin DataTables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it depends on what you need it for... if you just want to have columns hidden, then reveal them at a later time, then you'd do this to toggle the column (from the [docs](http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html))

```
function fnShowHide( iCol )
{
  /* Get the DataTables object again - this is not a recreation, just a get of the object */
  var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();

  var bVis = oTable.fnSettings().aoColumns[iCol].bVisible;
  oTable.fnSetColumnVis( iCol, bVis ? false : true );
}
```

The plugin doesn't have an interface (as far as I'm aware) for adding columns, but ordinary jQuery seems to do the trick:

```
$('#example thead tr,#example tfoot tr').append('<th>New title</th>');
$('#example tbody tr').append('<td />');
```